# My harddrive is not accessible in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, data-recovery

I have taken back of my all previous work of client and projects in my personal portable harddrive 2 week ago but right now I am not able to access it in my system on Ubuntu or in Windows either. My harddrive is showing in disks in Ubuntu.

I cannot format my harddrive because there is a lot of my previous work on it. I need to recover it before formatting it.

[image]

Comment: Might want to take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files and maybe try an application like [Testdisk step-by-step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) and see if you can recover your files that way.

Comment: It would be better to mount it in Windows and use tools like Recuva.

Comment: In a terminal window, run the command `journalctl --follow`, then connect your disk. Do you see any interesting messages?

Comment: Could you provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb`?